# Jackson Jsonparser not allowing me to specify field naming policy?

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
```

I'm getting an error and compiler warning from intellij under the constructor, and when attempting to compile it says that

```
java: no suitable method found for configure(org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser.Feature,boolean) method


(actual argument org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser.Feature cannot be converted to com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator.Feature by method invocation conversion)
```

This method and it's constructor with exactly these parameters also appear and are available with the intellisense.

Can anyone think of a reason for this nonsense?

Thanks for any help, I really can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

-Adam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the doc for [ObjectMapper](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.4.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html), you can clearly see that it specifies a configure method with the following type signature:

`configure(JsonParser.Feature f, boolean state)`

However, you seem to be using two different versions of Jackson. One coming from codehaus and the other from fasterxml, as noted by the second line in your error. To test this or temporarily fix this, try doing this instead:

```
mapper.configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
```

or, conversely, instantiate the other ObjectMapper:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper mapper = new org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper();
```

EDIT: To be clear, do one of the above, not both!

Comment: For the benefit of accumulated knowledge on stackoverflow, this solution works :)